# How do i hide a option using php.!

Tags: php

I am working on a part were user post their status.! And that the post will be seen by other members in community, and their "i want to hide **delete post** option form other members of group/community" or simply **delete post** option only available to  user who has posted it..! By taking below advice i have edited my code accordingly but its giving me a error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

**code.php**

```
echo '<div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="social-feed-box">' .if($_SESSION['via'] == $row['via']){.               

                    '<div class="pull-right social-action dropdown">
                        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn-white">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu m-t-xs">
                            <li><a href="post_delete.php">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>' .}. '<div>.....
```

Comment: Do a SQL query to the DB, check if the poster's ID matches with the session id (_if you have this_) and then put the delete link/button in the `elseif` statement.

Comment: You can easily do that by a check `if($logged_in_user == $posted_user_id){//display delete button html code}` ?

Comment: as @Rishi mentioned , check if the logged user = post user id , but you have to add more security layer in the delete page/action

Comment: sir i have done some thing by taking your advice and updated my code..but its giving out error as Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) plz help me out.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```html
<?php
$_SESSION['via'] =1;
$row['via'] =1;

 
  
echo '<div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="social-feed-box">';

    if($_SESSION['via'] == $row['via']) { 
     
    echo '<div class="pull-right social-action dropdown">
                        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle btn-white">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu m-t-xs">
                            <li><a href="post_delete.php">Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>';
     
    }
          echo  '</div>';


 
?>
```